# Frequently used functions in model or helper

Tags: model, helper

I made a curl function so that I can make an api call. Now the function I created is in helper and I call it with Mage::helper('xyz')->curlGet($url). This works but I am not sure whether this is the  proper way. I have seen functions created in models. Is there some kind of function convention in magento? Sorry for sounding silly, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to curl an external website then it belongs in a helper (what you did is correct).

On the other hand, if you are trying to access some data within Magento then a [Model](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento#5) is the way to go.

Sometimes you may have an interesting situation where `curl` is pulling data from another site and that data is model-like. In this case I would suggest creating a model that calls your helper, this way the curl call is abstracted.

See example below:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Charity extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
      public function getCurlData($url){
             if($url){  // make sure url is passed
                  $data = Mage::helper('xyz')->curlGet($url);
                  return $data;
              }
              return false; // if the url wasn't passed we want to know about it
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

create an model File in your Exention's model directory

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Charity
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

public function ModelExample()
{
     echo "Foo Bar";
     return ;
}

}
```

Now you can call this model function by `Mage::getModel('namespace/module')->ModelExample();`

Follow these [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) series by Alan Storm